# Error occurred on playing youtube using MyToolkit in Lumia 520

Tags: c#, xaml, youtube, windows-phone, mytoolkit

I am getting

```
Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

this error on

```
MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync() method
```

This is specific to Lumia 520, I checked it on other devices and it works fine.
Is there any problem or any other way to play youtube video on phone.

I installed some other app which plays youtube videos on 520. So Is I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, I am wrong and its not the problem with 520. Actually date and time of the phone is not correct which causes some certificate problem. That's why its not working on phone but on emulator. 
Thanks